# Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a table in mysql database. Below is the error that i am receiving. I have tried almost everything but i am not sure exactly what am i missing . Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note:- earlier i was getting the same error but after excluding two classes of jpa(using @springbootspplication), code was working fine. But now it is giving the same error.

> Error

```
2018-10-06 19:42:42.714  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager      : Using DataSource [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2018-10-06 19:42:42.870  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-06 19:42:43.292  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@41540924: startup date [Sat Oct 06 19:42:33 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-06 19:42:43.355  WARN 1672 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-10-06 19:42:43.402  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Index]}" onto public java.lang.String com.bookstore.HomeController.Index()
2018-10-06 19:42:43.402  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/myAccount]}" onto public java.lang.String com.bookstore.HomeController.myAccount()
2018-10-06 19:42:43.417  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-06 19:42:43.417  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-06 19:42:43.464  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-06 19:42:43.464  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-06 19:42:43.729  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2018-10-06 19:42:44.151  WARN 1672 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-10-06 19:42:44.151  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-10-06 19:42:44.151  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-06 19:42:44.166  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-10-06 19:42:44.182  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-06 19:42:44.229  INFO 1672 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-06 19:42:44.541 ERROR 1672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.bookstore.BookStoreApplication.main(BookStoreApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

this is a hibernate config that i have created manually

> HibernateConfig.java

```
package com.bookstore;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
/**
 * Created by Java Developer Zone on 25-08-2017.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;    // It will automatically read database properties from application.properties and create DataSource object
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {            // creating session factory
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.javadeveloperzone.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {                  // configure hibernate properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }



    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")                      // creating transaction manager factory
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

> application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstoredatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Qwerty123@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=false
```

> pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookStore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bookStore</name>
    <description>frontend part of bookstore</description>



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> 


           <!-- HIBERNATE -->










    <!-- Spring ORM, works with Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

> bookStoreApplication.java

```
package com.bookstore;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;


@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

public class BookStoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookStoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> User.java

```
package com.bookstore;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
private Long id;

    @Column(name="username")
private String username;
    @Column(name="password")
private String password;
    @Column(name="firstname")
private String firstName;
    @Column(name="lastname")
private String lastName;
    @Column(name="mobileno")
private String mobileNo;

@Column(name="emailId",nullable=false,updatable=false)
private String emailId;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}
public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
private boolean enabled=true;
}
```

Please let me know if any additional details is needed. i would be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps and you would be good

1. Remove everything as `@SpringBootApplication` will do auto configure for you as you are already excluding custom configuration so nothing required.

   ```
      @SpringBootApplication
      public class BookStoreApplication {

         public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(BookStoreApplication.class, args);
      }
    }
   ```
2. Remove all dependencies except web, Jpa,thymeleaf, MySQL connector( remove version from it as parent will take care of it) and test, dev tools. As Jpa will take care of your ORM etc..

**UPDATE**

1. here is your final updated pom

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>BookStore</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>BookStore</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Here is Main application class:

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class BookStoreApplication {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(BookStoreApplication.class, args);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Here is your updated Entity class:

   ```
   import javax.persistence.*;

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "user")
   public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="username")
   private String username;
   @Column(name="password")
   private String password;
   @Column(name="firstname")
   private String firstName;
   @Column(name="lastname")
   private String lastName;
   @Column(name="mobileno")
   private String mobileNo;

   private boolean enabled=true;

   @Column(name="emailId",nullable=false,updatable=false)
   private String emailId;
   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getUsername() {
       return username;
   }
   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }
   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   public String getMobileNo() {
       return mobileNo;
   }
   public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
       this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
   }
   public String getEmailId() {
       return emailId;
   }
   public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
       this.emailId = emailId;
   }
   public boolean isEnabled() {
       return enabled;
   }
   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
       this.enabled = enabled;
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I tried doing as per your instruction , but seems like the issue is still there.   "Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"

Comment: Please do mvn clean install or clear cache/restart IDE and show me your entity class

Comment: If possible share your code on GitHub as there seems lot of conflict so I can look at

Comment: i have tried cleaning the everything but still no luck

Comment: also i have added the entity class.

Comment: Now can you please update your latest pom let me check at my end

Comment: @user8886938 check my updated answer, I have posted pom, main class and entity..please match your replace..

Comment: Can you please post your code on github or we can do zoom.us to see your code..let me know

Comment: zoom us sounds great

Comment: Hi kj007..... So i created two spring boot project having same database. but in one project , it was unable to add "findOne()" method of CrudRepository. i tried downgrading my spring release from 2.0.6 to 1.4.3 which resolved this error. but now i am getting "cannot connect to the database" error. while the other project is communicating with database. Really appreciate your help here